# GCKCastOptions Error. Swift 3.0 Downloaded using cocoapods v 2.10.4

Tags: swift3, chromecast, google-cast

I used CocoaPods to download 'google-cast-sdk' version **2.10.4** and 'google-cast-remote-display-sdk'. My existing project is in Swift 3. I get an error when instantiating **GCKCastOptions** . I noticed that GCKCastOptions.h header file seems to be missing in this version.
Is there a workaround to this?

**EDIT:**

Downloading *google-cast-sdk* along with *google-cast-remote-display-sdk* using cocoapods downloads the v2 version of this currently. GCKCastOptions is available only in **v3**.
Hence the error!
Remove *google-cast-remote-display-sdk* and you will download v3 version of *google-cast-sdk* .

Comment: What is the exact error message?